# Improve performance in SQL query with many RIGHT OUTER JOIN and ORDERING

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Oracle database is used
There are SALES table and a lot of dictionary tables DICT_1, DICT_2,... DIC_N.
Users can change SALES tables (insert update delete) and ask result data like:

```
SELECT 
S.ID as ID,
RPAD(D1.NAME, 10) || LPAD(D1.NAME, 10) as NAME,
    CASE
      WHEN D2.count > 0 THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
    END
as FLAG
D3.FIELD as SOME_FIELD_3
D4.FIELD as SOME_FIELD_4
D5.FIELD as SOME_FIELD_5

FROM SALES S,  DICT_1 D1, DICT_2 D2, DICT_3 D3, DICT_4 D4, DICT_5 D5
WHERE
    S.D1_ID = D1.ID(+) 
AND  S.D2_ID = D2.ID(+)
AND  S.D3_ID = D3.ID(+)
AND  S.D4_ID = D4.ID(+)
AND  S.D5_ID = D5.ID(+)

ORDER BY NAME;
```

So try to join dictionary to SALE in case no sutch dictionary set null and calculate additional field from dictionary fields and SALES. Oredering can be applaed to any field from select (for example NAME, FLAG, ...). Withot order by query is quite fast but with ordering performance goes down. 
I propose to use ORACLE MATERIALIZED VIEW but because User often update SALES table reject this aproach.
Could you please support with decision how to improve perfomance this query with right outer join and order by calculeted field.

Comment: Is that some kind of ancient right join syntax or?

Comment: First, switch to modern, explicit join syntax. Also, most people have enough problems with LEFT JOIN, and find RIGHT JOIN even more confusing. So, do everybody a favor, and switch to LEFT JOIN!

Comment: Unfortunately syntax can not affect perfomance

Answer (score 0):

I am happy with your syntax.  But I am interested in your statement :

> Withot order by query is quite fast but with ordering performance goes down

With an ORDER BY clause the database must retrieve all rows and then order the data before returning the result set to you.  Without the ORDER BY the database can return batches of data as soon as they've been retrieved.  Performance for the whole result set is almost certainly unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that only ORDER BY slows the SQL, the issue is not with fetching data but sorting it. So, even if you have a materialised view with precomputed data, when the data needs to be sorted dynamically with different field each time, the SQL will take time.

A better approach would be
1. Discuss with Business/Clients to identify most frequently used FEW sorting columns.
2. create indexes on these identified columns. (Must be few or we will end up with lots of indexes useful only for this SQL)
3. Rewrite SQL as below.
WITH sorted_result AS ( SELECT indexed_columns FROM  ORDER BY indexed_Columns) SELECT  FROM , sorted_result WHERE  AND sorted_result.ID = SALES.ID

Table access is avoided until sorting completes in the WITH clause. The outer SQL uses the sorted result set to get you the result in batches / first_rows_n. With only the index being accessed for sorts, the query should be faster.

Hope this helps.